# Некоторые особенности синтаксиса PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы `transmission` и `car`:

```
 id_transmission |   name   
-----------------+----------
               1 | trans_01
               2 | trans_02
               3 | trans_03

 id_car | name  | id_transmission // references transmission (id_transmission)
--------+-------+----------------
      1 | car_1 |  1            
      2 | car_2 |  2
```

Я делаю запрос чтобы найти неиспользуемые детали:

```
select m.name from motor as m
left outer join car as c 

on m.id_motor = c.id_motor where c.name is null;
```

Все хорошо я получаю именно неиспользуемые детали. Но когда я меняю `where` на `and` и делаю такой запрос:

```
select t.name from transmission as t
left outer join car as c 

on t.id_transmission = c.id_transmission and c.name is null;
```

То получаю вообще все детали.

Как такое получается почему в данном контексте `where` и `and` не синонимы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отбор в секции ON выполняется ДО связывания, а в секции WHERE - после связывания.

Первый запрос работает так, как Вы задумали, а вот второй решает другую задачу, а именно "получить все трансмиссии, которые используются хотя бы в одной машине и у которых поле наименования не пусто".

**UPD:** был невнимателен. Второй запрос решает задачу "получить все трансмиссии, количество дубликатов равно количеству использований, или 1 для неиспользуемых нигде".

Comment: но в примере с and у меня выводятся все трансмиссии и те которые не используются. Вы ничего не путаете?

Comment: А, у Вас же таблица трансмиссий (а в текстах запросов - моторов) слева... ну тогда вообще выведутся все, вне зависимости от того, использованы они где или нет. Просто если используются - то будет соответствующее количество дубликатов.

Comment: да пардон исправил, просто у меня там несколько аналогичных таблиц с деталями они только названиями отличаются.